# What is "load" in System Load Indicator?

Tags: system-tray, system-monitor

System Load Indicator displays plots of CPU activity, memory use, hard drive i/o, etc. There's also a "Load" graph, but I don't know what it means. What exactly is this "Load"?

Comment: "What is load" .. I love that song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means system load, check these resources:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/67759/how-to-understand-the-memory-usage-and-load-average-in-linux-server
- https://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-in-unix-linux
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33203/how-does-load-average-work-with-modern-cpus
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9001

Comment: Rather than just cite the other sources, you should also include the explanation yourself ;)

Answer (score 4):

Short summary from two different sources.

From `en.wikipedia.org/`

> The load average represents the average system load over a period of
>   time. It conventionally appears in the form of three numbers which
>   represent the system load during the last one-, five-, and
>   fifteen-minute periods.
>
> [...]
>
> An idle computer has a load number of 0. Each process using or waiting 
>   for CPU (the ready queue or run queue) increments the load number by
>   1. Most UNIX systems count only processes in the running (on CPU) or runnable (waiting for CPU) states. However, Linux also includes
>   processes in uninterruptible sleep states (usually waiting for disk
>   activity), which can lead to markedly different results if many
>   processes remain blocked in I/O due to a busy or stalled I/O
>   system.[1] This, for example, includes processes blocking due to an
>   NFS server failure or to slow media (e.g., USB 1.x storage devices).
>   Such circumstances can result in an elevated load average, which does
>   not reflect an actual increase in CPU use (but still gives an idea on
>   how long users have to wait).
>
> [...]
>
> For single-CPU systems that are CPU bound, one can think of load
>   average as a percentage of system utilization during the respective
>   time period. For systems with multiple CPUs, one must divide the
>   number by the number of processors in order to get a comparable
>   percentage.

From `man uptime`

> System load averages is the average number of processes that are
>   either in a runnable or uninterruptable state. A process in a runnable
>   state is either using the CPU or waiting to use the CPU. A process in
>   uninterruptable state is waiting for some I/O access, eg waiting for
>   disk. The averages are taken over the three time intervals. Load
>   averages are not normalized for the number of CPUs in a system, so a
>   load average of 1 means a single CPU system is loaded all the time
>   while on a 4 CPU system it means it was idle 75% of the time.

To answer the original question, it is the load average for the past 1 minute.