# CPU Load Showing Greater Than 25

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

I have been recently using the system monitor to track my memory usage. When checking I noticed that my Load is showing up as 25 or greater. I noticed the cpu doesn't seem that taxed though so I wonder why the load would be so high. The computer has an AMD A10-7850K 3.7GHz Quad-Core Processor and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

[image: a screenshot of the system monitor on navbar]

I'm mainly wondering if there is something I should check further or what my options are if this is indeed bad like I think it is.

**edited:**

uptime

```
20:34:02 up 1 day, 22:12,  8 users,  load average: 4.92, 4.70, 4.7
```

ps aux | grep kworker | grep -v u | grep -v H | wc -l

```
13
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what Load actually means: http://askubuntu.com/questions/556316/what-is-load-in-system-load-indicator

Comment: A load of 35.90 is somewhat unusual (but one can easily create loads of over 1000 without much effort). When you have such a high load average: Could you edit your question and add the output for the `uptime` command, so that we can also observe the 5 and 15 minutes load averages (I assume the 35.90 number is the 1 minute load average); Could you also post the output for this `ps aux | grep kworker | grep -v u | grep -v H | wc -l` as there has been a relatively new issue with a high number of kworker threads, but I didn't think it had migrated back to any 16.04 kernels.

Comment: The fix for the kworker threads issue for the SLUB allocator has been identified and should be released in the next round of kernel updates.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/+source/linux/+bug/1649905

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate of the existing reference. The load of 35.90 with, apparently, not a lot of real load should be pursued. The statement "From what I understand this number is not supposed to be higher than the amount of cores you have." is incorrect, as explained by the reference.

Comment: @DougSmythies I added the information you requested. Thanks everyone for the clarification. I think in hindsight I should have researched a bit more on what exactly load was.

Comment: O.K. that looks very normal, depending on what you were doing. What I really want is that stuff when you have a load average of >25.